# How to run wires through a wall with existing wall wiring? (Tight Spaces)

Tags: wiring, walls

So I have a coaxial cable that I need to run from my TV to my sound system and there are already holes in the wall with wires from the last home owner. I've already tried using fishtape to run the cable through but there are too many twists and turns in the route. Are there any other options that I can explore to wire the cable through?

Comment: Are you replacing the wires or running more?  Unless they're stapled, it's really easy to use old wires to pull new wires.

Comment: I'm running more wires. The existing wires are not stapled but they are jam packed into the holes that are drilled into the 2x4 studs.

Comment: Use a flex-shaft drill to bore a new hole to run the new cables? Haven't used one, but they have the advantage of minimizing the need to damage the wall surface... Note that code foes set limits on how many power wires may pass through a given sixe jole; I'm not sure how low-voltage cables interact with that rule.

Comment: @kelsham - there is no bundling issue with low voltage cables.  Using a flex bit can be tricky along existing wiring.

Comment: @SwagPanda - I gather from your comments that you're trying to run the cable horizontally - I'd just do as Ed Beal says in his answer.

Answer (score 1):

their are times I will cut a hole for an old work box, drill from the attic down or from the crawl space up (attic down is easier as you can see the 2x4) drop a string with a small 2oz fishing weight,  hook wire on and pull up, then do the same at the location of your sound system , install an old work box in each location these are the boxes that have wings that pull them tight to the sheetrock, or a low voltage ring that snaps in place and you fold the metal tabs around the sheetrock, then put a coax cover plate and it looks very profesional.

Answer (score 0):

I have had good luck disconnecting one of the existing wires and tying two "pilot" lines to it.  Then, I use the wire to pull the pilot lines back through and untie one pilot line, leaving the other tied to the wire.  I pull the wire back through and reconnect it.  This leaves a pilot line that I can use to pull new cables.  Obviously, you should ensure that the wire you use to pull the two pilot lines is not hot before using it for that purpose.

Comment: If you are talking about line voltage electrical cables, these are usually stapled (if installed correctly). Also, repeatedly pulling electrical cables beyond the original installation is an invitation to damaging them. A broken AC cable in a wall is an ugly thing.

Comment: @bib I was assuming that the caution about hot wires would be enough.  However, he is right, SwapPanda, do this cautiously and not too much.

Comment: Thanks. But there are no electrical shocks associated with this project, the nearest hot wire is 6 feet away horizontally and 2 feet away vertically. The problem is that there are already 6 existing cables running through the holes in the studs and they are very tight, almost unable to be pulled, there's no slack to it.